# sharepoint combining multiple calendars spquery arraylist sorting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my code, I have stored all calendar events in an arraylist called "arlist". I would like to sort the arraylist by event start date so all the events are sorted.  Any ideas on how I can sort the arraylist?

Thanks!
J

```
foreach (SPWeb web in CurrentSiteCollection.AllWebs)
        {
            SPListCollection weblists = web.Lists;
            try
            {
                SPList Calist = weblists["Calendar"];
                SPQuery Iquery = new SPQuery();
                Iquery.ExpandRecurrence = true;

                Iquery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='IsPublic'/>" +
                   "<Value Type= 'bit'>1</Value></Eq>" +
                   "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef  Name=\"EndDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" />" +
                   "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>             </And></Where>";
                Iquery.CalendarDate = sdate;
                SPListItemCollection gItems = Calist.GetItems(Iquery);
                if (gItems.Count > 0)
                {

                    arlist.Add(gItems);
                    urlist.Add(string.Format("{0}/{1}?   ID=",Calist.ParentWebUrl,Calist.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a generic collection instead of ArrayList?

declaration

```
 List<SPListItem> arlist = new List<SPListItem>();
```

do this

```
foreach (SPListItem Item in gItems) {
arlist.Add(Item);
}
```

instead of`arlist.Add(gItems);`

Finally when you are done looping through all the sub sites and adding all the events, sort like this

```
arlist.OrderBy((x) => x.Item("EventDate"));
```

Do not forget to add the namespace system.collections.generic.